# How to Lookup for 2 columns in Excel and Return Value if second column Matches

Tags: excel

I have one worksheet with All the URL's of 60 styles that have multiple Children styles that are different by colors.

For Example:

```
Website/SH70_BLACK_2.jpg,
Website/SH70_BLACK_3.jpg,
Website/SH70_BLUE_1.jpg,
Website/SH70_BLUE_2.jpg,
Website/GN02_PINK_2.jpg,
Website/GN02_PINK_3.jpg,
Website/GN02_PINK_4.jpg,
Website/GN02_YELLOW_1.jpg,
Website/GN02_YELLOW_2.jpg,
Website/GN02_YELLOW_3.jpg,
Website/GN02_YELLOW_4.jpg,
Website/GN03B_BLUE_1.jpg,
Website/GN03B_BLUE_2 (1).jpg,
Website/GN03B_BLUE_2.jpg,
Website/GN03B_BLUE_3.jpg,
Website/GN03B_GRAY_1.jpg,
Website/GN03B_GRAY_2.jpg,
Website/GN03B_GRAY_3.jpg,
Website/GN03B_GRAY_4.jpg,
Website/GN03B_RED_1.jpg,
```

And in my inventory program, the SKU is GN03B_RED, GN03B_GRAY and so on... I could do a "Text to column" in excel and separate SKU from color. 
But how do I Lookup for 2 columns in Excel and Return Value if second column Matches (ie; the color)?

Comment: Can you please explain how this is two columns? It looks like just one to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index and match together with array formula(ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=index(the column you want to return,match(1stlookupcol&2ndlookupcol,0))
```